# Under Ubuntu without a graphical interface, what command should I use to replace gnome-terminal

Tags: linux, qemu

My operating system is Ubuntu 18.4, and when I try to make the code given by the teacher, I got this:

```
root@ArcherJo:~/ucore_os_lab/labcodes_answer/lab1_result# make lab1-mon 
/bin/sh: 1: gnome-terminal: not found
Makefile:202: recipe for target 'lab1-mon' failed
make: *** [lab1-mon] Error 127
```

Find the corresponding line of Makefile

```
201 lab1-mon: $(UCOREIMG)
202         $(V)$(TERMINAL) -e "$(QEMU) -S -s -d in_asm -D $(BINDIR)/q.log -monitor stdio -hda $< -serial null"
203         $(V)sleep 2
204         $(V)$(TERMINAL) -e "gdb -q -x tools/lab1init"
...
217 TERMINAL        :=gnome-terminal
```

Then I realized that this might be because my system is without a graphical interface, which means I cannot use `gnome-terminal` to open a new terminal.

So what improvements should I make to achieve similar results?

Since the Makefile is too long, let me outline the background.This is an OS experimental course. We use qemu for hardware simulation and then run our own OS on it.

*Here are some more code I think you may need them.*

```
25 ifndef QEMU
26 QEMU := $(shell if which qemu-system-i386 > /dev/null; \
27         then echo 'qemu-system-i386'; exit; \
28         elif which i386-elf-qemu > /dev/null; \
29         then echo 'i386-elf-qemu'; exit; \
30         else \
31         echo "***" 1>&2; \
32         echo "*** Error: Couldn't find a working QEMU executable." 1>&2; \
33         echo "*** Is the directory containing the qemu binary in your PATH" 1>&2; \
34         echo "***" 1>&2; exit 1; fi)
35 endif
...
71 BINDIR  := bin
...
170 UCOREIMG        := $(call totarget,ucore.img)
```

Comment: Can you edit the Makefile or does it have to remain the same?

Comment: Running it as `make TERMINAL='sh -c'` will probably work for the first command, but that makefile wants to start qemu and gdb in two separate windows. The best thing would be to install some lightweight graphical interface; you could probably do with a wrapper script which calls `shift; tmux split-window "$@"`, but why bother?

Comment: Please mention what can you install on that machine. Eg. if you can install tmux.

Comment: @Aplet123 Yes , i can edit it.

Comment: @mosvy I successfully installed the tmux !

Comment: Start tmux, and inside tmux try `make TERMINAL="sh -c 'tmux split-window  \"\$\$@\"'"`. This should split the window in 3 -- one for your shell, one for qemu, and one for gdb. Switch between them with `Ctrl-B o` and make them the same size with `Ctrl-B Alt-2`

Comment: @mosvy Thank you very much for your solution. This method does seem to solve my problem successfully !

But I'm sorry I didn't understand you well. . . .

Did you mean when I ```make``` in the window, change it to ```make TERMINAL="sh -c 'tmux split-window \"\$\$@\"'"```. Then, run ```make lab1-mon``` again. But when I did this, I got the same error. 

However I believe that this should be the problem of my usage

Comment: `make lab1-mon TERMINAL="sh -c 'tmux split-window \"\$\$@\"'"` just once, ie the first command from your Q, with the `TERMINAL=...` overriding the value from inside the Makefile. Instead of that ugly escaping, you can also edit the Makefile and change the `$(V)$(TERMINAL) -e ...` to `$(V) tmux split-window ...`.

Comment: @mosvy Oh my God! Thank you SOOOOOOOOOO MUCH!

I added -h to the second split screen command. Now it looks wonderful !